# Unable to login to website through python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to login to a website in order to get some data. I have noticed that there is not form-data in the 'post' method but there is a 'request payload'. Furthermore, when I login in I cannot see anymore the login post method. Here is a screenshot of the network post login method:

[image: description]

When I login the next page showed is I use the following code in order to login:

```
 import requests
 urlData = 'https://b*********.dk/Account/Market'
 urlLogin = 'https://b**********an.dk/


 with requests.Session() as c:
     urlLogin = 'https://b*************n.dk/Authorization/
     c.get(urlLogin)
     NetSession = c.cookies['ASP.NET_SessionId']
     login_data = {
                   'ASP.NET_SessionId': NetSession,
                   'username':"A******",
                   'Password':"q******",
                   'remmemberMe': True
                   }

lol = c.post(urlLogin, data=login_data)
print(lol.text)
```

Running this code the following is outputed:

```
{"Processed":true,"Message":"The user name or password provided is incorrect.","NeedResetPassword":false}
```

When i input a wrong password the `Processed` value is `false`, while with correct credentials is `true`. But it deosnt login. Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: You're going to want to change that password/username ... even if you remove it via edit, pretty sure that's going to now be a permanent part of the history.

Comment: On a more useful to the question note... I see ASP.NET; in my experience, there is frequently one or more hidden values passed in to their forms / form like things.  I'd suggest using fiddler or similar to see exactly what gets passed by a real browser and making sure your code sends the exact same thing.  (For one project, that included setting the agent requests uses to match firefox as otherwise it was getting treated different) (Also also... in the screen shot, you have username and password; in the code, you have username and Password... check that you have the case right)

Comment: What's the behaviour in the browser? It's an XHR request so I'm wondering if they inspect the Processed item first, and the Message is irrelevant?

Comment: @dwightgunning I think its not irrelevant. Because if i try to use `.get()` a protected webpage url I get an error `TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'`

Answer (score 2):

As you've already correctly noticed, the original credentials are not sent using form encoding (meaning `&user=alice&password=secret`), but are **JSON encoded** (so rather `{"user":"alice", "password": "secret"}`). You can also see this in the request's `Content-Type` header, which is `application/json` where (as opposed to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` otherwhise).

For your custom request to work, you propably also need to send **JSON-encoded data**. This is [documented in length in the official Documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), so I'll just give the short version:

```
import json

# Build session and request body just like you already did in your question
# ...

headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json"}
lol = c.post(urlLogin, data=json.dumps(login_data), headers=headers)
print(lol.json())
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added these lines but it didnt had different results.